# How to add parameters to a HttpRequest programatically in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I use JMeter in our product performance testing now.

I have a performace test scenario below:

1. Exract 1000 unique IDs from a request A.
2. Add the 1000 unique IDs to next request B as "form parameters". check the request B response time.

The request B is like:

Method: Post

URL:  http://www.aaa.com/abc/def

Form parameters:

para1  :   value1

para2  :   value2

ID     :   ID1

ID     :   ID2

ID     :   ID3

......

ID     :   ID1000

I know this request isn't a Canonical usage of http request. but it is used in our product for years.

Now I get the 1000 unique IDs from request A with the help of "regular expression extractor",

My question is:
how to pass the variables to request B, and set the 1000 IDs as "form parameters" of request B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler where you need to add 1000 parameters
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
   1.upto(vars.get('ID_matchNr') as int, index -> {
       def parameter = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('ID', vars.get('ID_' + index))
       data.addArgument(parameter)
   })
   sampler.setArguments(data)
   ```
3. That's it, the JSR223 PreProcessor will read all the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which start with `ID_1` and ending with `ID_XXXX` and add a corresponding parameter to the HTTP Request sampler

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter context: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It can add the IDs to the request now.
 
Another question is: 

I already added another 2 parameters in request B, but the variables in the script override these 2 parameters in request. How to keep the 2 parameters in request and add others from scripts programmatically?

Comment: I got the expected result after change the first line to "def data=sampler.getArguments()". Thank you, @Dmitri T